# How can I supply data to yield in my rails partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I'm trying to render a partial with a certain layout file.  But be able to specify unique values for that specific partial.  Below are the current files I have, but all that happens is the `yield` keywords both show the collection value.  I'd like to pass a custom "title" and show the collection in the "body".

**application/_news_article.html.erb**

```
<!-- application/_news_article.html.erb  --> 
<% if news_article.report_text.present? %>
  <div class="news_article_entry">
    <div class="text-box">
      <span><%= "#{news_article.published_date.strftime("%D")}" %></span> -
      <%= "#{news_article.report_text}" %>
    </div>
    <% if news_article.impact_text.present? %>
      <div class="impact-text" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
        title="<%= news_article.impact_text %>">Analysis</div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <hr />
<% end %>
```

**application/_news_articles.html.erb**

```
<!-- application/_news_articles.html.erb  --> 
<%= render partial: "news_article", collection: articles %>
```

**layouts/_panel_box_scrollable.html.erb**

```
<!-- layouts/_panel_box_scrollable.html.erb  --> 
<div class="panel panel-default skill-evaluation-box">
  <div class="skill-heading">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <%= "#{yield :title}".upcase %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="skill-body scrollable">
    <%= yield :body %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**schools/show.html.erb**

```
 <!-- schools/show.html.erb  --> 
 <%= render partial: 'news_articles', layout: "layouts/panel_box_scrollable", locals: { articles: @articles } %>
```

Comment: you can use `content_for(:something) do ... end` block to be displayed in your matching `yield(:something)`

Comment: @MrYoshiji, I've been trying that with no luck - which file should i try it in? I've been putting that in `application/_news_articles.html.erb`

Comment: have you tried to put `<% content_for(:title) { "some test ttitle" } %>` in any of your partial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yield is where the partial will be rendered. If you want to render a title you need to pass in a title through `locals` or use a variable potentially on one of your models or set in the controller. In this case if you want to render a title do something like:

```
<%= render partial: 'news_articles', layout: "layouts/panel_box_scrollable", locals: { articles: @articles, title: 'My Title' } %>
```

Then in your layout do:

```
<div class="panel panel-default skill-evaluation-box">
  <div class="skill-heading">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <%= title.upcase %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="skill-body scrollable">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</div>
```